# How to remove the Header from my App? Why is the Header displayed?

Tags: javascript, react-native, header, styles, react-navigation

How to remove the Header from my App? Why is the Header displayed?

I want to remove the title from the Header, since each page has its own title, and that title takes up space from the screens.

I do not understand why it is displayed. I'm following a tutorial and as many times as I go through, I don't see a way to remove this.
I have followed the official documentation, but I cannot get rid of this nonsensical Header.

The navigation is handled from the AppStack.js file and the Header titles displayed are handled from the <Tab.Navigator> <Tab.Screen /> </Tab.Navigator>, but this is really the bottom tabs, and however, they are also displayed in the Header.
I show some image of what I cannot remove

How do I remove this Header which is unnecessary?

I have the correct dependencies:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^ 1.10.3",
"react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^ 1.1.4",
"react-native-reanimated": "^ 2.2.3",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^ 3.3.2",
"react-native-screens": "^ 3.8.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^ 8.1.0",
"react-native-webview": "^ 11.14.1",
"styled-components": "^ 5.3.3"
```

AppStack.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeSreen'
import ChatScreen from '../screens/ChatScreen'
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/ProfileScreen'
import AddPostScreen from '../screens/AddPostScreen'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const FeedStack = ({ navigation }) => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Social React Native"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          color: '#2e64e5',
          fontFamily: 'Kufam-SemiBoldItalic',
          fontSize: 18,
        },
        headerStyle: {
          shadowColor: '#fff',
          elevation: 0,
        },
        headerRight: () => (
          <View style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
            <FontAwesome5.Button
              name="plus"
              size={22}
              backgroundColor="#fff"
              color="#2e64e5"
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddPost')}
            />
          </View>
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="AddPost"
      component={AddPostScreen}
      options={{

        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#2e64e515',
          shadowColor: '#2e64e515',
          elevation: 0,
        },
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
        headerBackImage: () => (
          <View style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}>
            <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={25} color="#2e64e5" />
          </View>
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="HomeProfile"
      component={ProfileScreen}
      options={{

        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          shadowColor: '#fff',
          elevation: 0,
        },
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
        headerBackImage: () => (
          <View style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}>
            <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={25} color="#2e64e5" />
          </View>
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
)

const ProfileStack = ({ navigation }) => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Profile"
      component={ProfileScreen}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
   
  </Stack.Navigator>
)

const AppStack = () => {
  const getTabBarVisibility = (route) => {
    const routeName = route.state
      ? route.state.routes[route.state.index].name
      : '';

    if (routeName === 'Chat') {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      activeTintColor: '#2e64e5'
    }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={FeedStack}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="home-outline"
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Messages"
        component={ChatScreen}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisibility(route),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons
              name="chatbox-ellipses-outline"
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStack}
        options={{
          // tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="person-outline" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

export default AppStack
```

IMAGES:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you using the AppStack ?

Comment: In a Routes file, and from there I wrap it in AuthProvider to send it to a protected App.
  Do you need me to show any more files?

Comment: No just wanted to know whether you have anything else inside the Navigation container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add options={{ headerShown: false }}

```html
 <Tab.Screen
        name="Messages"
        component={ChatScreen}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisibility(route),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons
              name="chatbox-ellipses-outline"
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
```